# How can I export tiles of OpenStreetMap and use it in Flutter Application?

Tags: android, flutter, maps, openstreetmap

I want to create an application for working with offline map of city.
I'm using a Flutter.

How can I download the tiles **ONLY OF ONE CITY** of OpenStreetMap and export this to Flutter application for offline using?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to use mbtiles ... See https://medium.com/@jamesayvaz/offline-maps-for-your-flutter-app-3ea64111b73c

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has been addressed in the Open Street Maps help pages:
https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/43792/can-i-download-osm-tiles-for-offline-use

Comment: I didn't find the solution here